# Asking users to chose a color from a palette and modifying SVG through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm stuck with this little project of mine. Essentially, I want to create a web page which allows users to select a color from a color palette and change the corresponding SVG's element based on the color the user selected.

1. I used JS Color for the color palette, but it has drawbacks (It keeps showing the hex value of the color and there's no way to hide it. I don't want my users to see like #FFFSAS values on the button or the text box where they select the color.
2. After they select the color from the palette, the corresponding svg element should show that color. I reached this step, but due to the drawback of step 1 I think I have to start all over again with a new technique.

Ideally I have a watch skeletal, whose band colors and frame colors can be changed by the users. Below is the code which I worked on using the JS color package. Any kind of help is appreciated

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

<p>'onchange' fires after the mouse button is released

<p>Frame color:
<input class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:66ccff}" onchange="update(this.jscolor)"> 
<p> Band color:
<input class="jscolor {valueElement:null}" onchange="update1(this.jscolor)" > 
<!--<br><button id="bgcolor-button" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(91, 171, 163); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Choose background</button>-->
<!--<button class="jscolor {valueElement: 'color_value'}" onchange="update(this.jscolor)">Pick a color</button>-->

<svg id="svg3436" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="97mm" width="50mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047">
 <metadata id="metadata3441">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g id="layer1">
  <path id="rect2985" style="fill:#800000" d="m451.87 620.2c13.102 0 23.641-9.5583 23.641-21.441v-246.33c0-11.883-10.539-21.441-23.641-21.441h-198.84c-13.102 0-23.641 9.5583-23.641 21.441v246.33c0 11.883 10.539 21.441 23.641 21.441h198.84zm-12.243-19.304h-172.71c-11.381 0-20.542-8.3084-20.542-18.63v-213.95c0-10.322 9.1608-18.63 20.542-18.63h172.71c11.381 0 20.542 8.3084 20.542 18.63v213.95c0 10.322-9.1608 18.63-20.542 18.63z"/>
  <path id="rect3758" style="fill:#000000" d="m424.31 822.02h-143.93l-20.297-197.66h188.21z"/>
  <path id="path3761" style="fill:#000000" d="m424.31 127.09h-143.93l-20.297 197.66h188.21z"/>
  <rect id="rect3763" style="fill:#000000" transform="scale(-1)" ry="9.3628" height="30.299" width="17.83" y="-543.22" x="-237.31"/>
  <rect id="rect3765" style="fill:#000000" transform="scale(-1)" ry="9.3628" height="30.299" width="17.83" y="-435.02" x="-237.31"/>
  <g id="layer1-7" transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 1646.9 -154.84)">
   <g id="g4387" transform="matrix(0 1.2805 -1.1172 0 1339.7 702.88)">
    <rect id="rect3769" style="fill:#000000" ry="1.6079" height="73.966" width="4.8882" y="621.88" x="458.59"/>
    <rect id="rect3771" style="fill:#000000" transform="matrix(-.69129 -.72257 .72257 -.69129 0 0)" ry="1.7366" height="79.883" width="4.8882" y="-120.82" x="-779.57"/>
    <circle id="path3773" style="fill:#000000" transform="translate(413.71 283.16)" cy="351.83" cx="47.071" r="6.2762"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
<script>
function update(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    var svgDoc = document.getElementById('svg3436');
    var paths = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
    var path = paths[0];
    alert(jscolor);
    path.style.fill= jscolor;
}
function update1(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    var svgDoc = document.getElementById('svg3436');
    var paths = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
    var path = paths[1];
    var path1 = paths[2];
        alert(jscolor);
    path.style.fill= jscolor;
    path1.style.fill= jscolor;

}

</script>

Change type of frame:
<button id="btnt1" onclick="loadimg()"> Frame 1</button>
<img id="image1" src="9.png" height="97mm" width="50mm" style="visibility:hidden">
<script>
    function loadimg(){
        var svgDoc = document.getElementById("svg3436");
        svgDoc.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("image1").style.display = visible;

    }
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the manufacturer of the watch/band does not have every color, I would suggest merely adding the available colors via a drop-down select with options.
Below is an example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>

<p>Frame color:
<p><div style=padding:5px;width:80px; id=frameColorDiv><select id="frameColorSelect" onChange=frameColorSelected()>
<option value="#000000">Black</option>
<option value="#CD7F32">Bronze</option>
<option value="#D4AF37">Gold</option>
<option value="#C0C0C0">Silver</option>
</select></div></p>
<p> Band color:
<p><div style=padding:5px;width:80px; id=bandColorDiv><select id="bandColorSelect" onChange=bandColorSelected()>
<option value="#000000">Black</option>
<option value="#008080">Teal</option>
<option value="#483C32">Taupe</option>
<option value="#964B00">Brown</option>
<option value="#E0B0FF">Mauve</option>
</select></div></p>
<!--<br><button id="bgcolor-button" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(91, 171, 163); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Choose background</button>-->
<!--<button class="jscolor {valueElement: 'color_value'}" onchange="update(this.jscolor)">Pick a color</button>-->

<svg id="svg3436" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="97mm" width="50mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047">
 <metadata id="metadata3441">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g id="layer1">
  <path id="rect2985" style="fill:#800000" d="m451.87 620.2c13.102 0 23.641-9.5583 23.641-21.441v-246.33c0-11.883-10.539-21.441-23.641-21.441h-198.84c-13.102 0-23.641 9.5583-23.641 21.441v246.33c0 11.883 10.539 21.441 23.641 21.441h198.84zm-12.243-19.304h-172.71c-11.381 0-20.542-8.3084-20.542-18.63v-213.95c0-10.322 9.1608-18.63 20.542-18.63h172.71c11.381 0 20.542 8.3084 20.542 18.63v213.95c0 10.322-9.1608 18.63-20.542 18.63z"/>
  <path id="rect3758" style="fill:#000000" d="m424.31 822.02h-143.93l-20.297-197.66h188.21z"/>
  <path id="path3761" style="fill:#000000" d="m424.31 127.09h-143.93l-20.297 197.66h188.21z"/>
  <rect id="rect3763" style="fill:#000000" transform="scale(-1)" ry="9.3628" height="30.299" width="17.83" y="-543.22" x="-237.31"/>
  <rect id="rect3765" style="fill:#000000" transform="scale(-1)" ry="9.3628" height="30.299" width="17.83" y="-435.02" x="-237.31"/>
  <g id="layer1-7" transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 1646.9 -154.84)">
   <g id="g4387" transform="matrix(0 1.2805 -1.1172 0 1339.7 702.88)">
    <rect id="rect3769" style="fill:#000000" ry="1.6079" height="73.966" width="4.8882" y="621.88" x="458.59"/>
    <rect id="rect3771" style="fill:#000000" transform="matrix(-.69129 -.72257 .72257 -.69129 0 0)" ry="1.7366" height="79.883" width="4.8882" y="-120.82" x="-779.57"/>
    <circle id="path3773" style="fill:#000000" transform="translate(413.71 283.16)" cy="351.83" cx="47.071" r="6.2762"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
<script>
function frameColorSelected()
{
    var frameColor=frameColorSelect.options[frameColorSelect.selectedIndex].value
    var svgDoc = document.getElementById('svg3436');
    var paths = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
    var path = paths[0];
    path.style.fill= frameColor;
    frameColorDiv.style.background=frameColor
}
function bandColorSelected()
{
    var bandColor=bandColorSelect.options[bandColorSelect.selectedIndex].value
    var svgDoc = document.getElementById('svg3436');
    var paths = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
    var path = paths[1];
    var path1 = paths[2];

    path.style.fill= bandColor;
    path1.style.fill= bandColor;

    bandColorDiv.style.background=bandColor
}
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```